# How can Scott Summers see?

Tags: marvel, x-men, cyclops

Scott Summers (aka Cyclops) has super powerful energy beams constantly firing from his eyes.  The only way he can prevent the beams from destroying everything is by closing his eyes or by wearing protective eye wear (apparently sunglasses are impervious to his energy beam).  In any other instance, his eyes are firing a bright red beam of energy.  How can he see through that?

Comment: Very well, thanks for asking.

Comment: @Gallifreyan I was waiting for that from someone.  Thank you for not disappointing me.  Long live dad jokes!

Comment: @MagikarpMaster: apologies, I was in a work meeting — normally I wouldn’t leave someone waiting that long for this joke.